# How do I increase the number of workers in an industrial area?

Tags: cities-skylines

In the *Cities: Skylines - Industries* DLC, I have zoned a couple of forestry areas and built one of each type of building that is initially available; the main forestry building, a small plantation, a sawmill, and a storage yard. The industrial area itself covers a large area of the forestry natural resource. I long ago met the production criteria for levelling up (something like 5000/500) but I am stuck on the number of workers at roughly 90/150.

I assumed that in an industrial area zoned as a particular industry type, even the factories that get built by the AI would be related to that industry (but they don't seem to be) and the number of workers in the zone as a whole would be counted, but that does not seem to be the case. Is the only way to increase the number of workers to build more forestry specific buildings? Given that I am still at level 1 and only have one of each type of building, does it mean I have to build multiple plantations and sawmills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Given that I am still at level 1 and only have one of each type of building, does it mean I have to build multiple plantations and sawmills?"

Correct. Also ensure that:

1. Your city has industrial demand, so that workers will actually fill up open industry jobs.
2. Road connections to your industry buildings are not blocked by traffic, destroyed, flooded etc.
3. Industry buildings are not operating at reduced capacity. All utilities (electric, water, sewage) should be provided.

Comment: Thanks. Seems a bit daft having to build several of the same buildings. I have a similar question about increasing the attractiveness of my university campus. Seems like the only way to do that is to build multiples of the same building type.

Comment: I got my industrial areas up to level 3 quite quickly thanks to this answer, so thanks again.

Comment: @Darren : you will soon notice that Processors and Unique Factories will require a LOT of the base cargo, and a single plantation will not be enough to feed the rest of the chain.

Comment: @leokhorn yes, I’m finding I need to build a lot of extractor buildings in all my industrial areas to keep the unique factories supplied with the materials they need.